# How to supply data via COM3?

Tags: c++, windows

I have been tasked with testing a serial comms application.
This application listens on COM3.
How can I supply data via COM3 to test the code.
I have tried to have another application that supplies the data but as  I have discovered I can only have one application accessing COM3

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: You can tap into the serial stream using a logic analyzer. However I don't know if that will be a suitable solution for your problem since it includes additional hardware.

Comment: Please walk us through your research so far and the problem(s) you've encountered.

Comment: I now know that I CANNOT have 2 apps accessing the same COM port on the same PC and that I need some 3rd party sw. I work in a restricted environment where I cannot load software easily so this is going to have to wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most typical way is to connect some hardware to COM3 to communicate with.

If you are lacking such hardware or want to test what the application does when it gets garbage instead of what it is expecting there are applications which provide a "virtual serial port pair" which emulate both sides and you can connect your application to one port while using a second application to communicate via it's pair. The paired ports should behave as if they were physically connected by a wire.

Also if you need a specific port number because of how the application is written you can change port numbers by choosing the device in `Device Manager` going to `Properties` and than `Advanced` and changing `COM Port Number`. If it's already used by another device you have to change that first to have a different number.

Comment: a quick search for `virtual serial port pair` will show you several solutions, some of them freely available

Comment: If the app is hardcoded to listen on COM3, this will be difficult. But that would be a stupid app.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit would still be possible to change COM port numbers in device manager though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm, suppose so. You could add that information to your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can't yet, I'm at work and only have linux available, can't check if I'm right, and don't want to mislead people.

Comment: You can do it when you're sure :)